# Classic ASP - Strange Characters Instead of PNG

Tags: asp-classic

I'm using http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Query_View_with_a_Preview_Image%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Reference%7C_____43 to output some PNG files.

The last bit of the code is

```
    postResponse = httpRequest.ResponseText
    Response.ContentType = "image/png"
    response.BinaryWrite postResponse
```

This results in

```
ÿÿPNG
```

Any advice? I've tried replacing `BinaryWrite` with just `Write` and get

```
ï¿¿PNG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the following:

```
response.BinaryWrite httpRequest.responseBody
```

Comment: Yes yes yes! Any more info on this please?

Comment: to be honest, I just copied the solution from an old project of mine where I had the same issue. I assume the responseText is somehow decoded to acii whereas responseBody is the raw binary data.

Comment: @JanuszJasinski **responseBody**: Represents the response entity body as an array of unsigned bytes. This contains the raw undecoded bytes as received directly from the server. **responseText**: The response entity body as a string. [...] attempts to decode the response into a Unicode string.

Comment: So could I do something like <img src=""data:image/png;base64,"&Base64decode(httpRequest.responseBody)&"""> or will that fail? Presuming my function is fine